# SSML: Play audio

Tags: java, android, ssml

I am using Android Studio and Google Cloud Text-To-Speech.

In SSML, I would like to play audio (see the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/ssml#audio)). I know that I could play that audio file with Java only but I would like to know why it is not working with SSML. This is what I have tried:

```
"<speak>What you hear is: <audio src='"+ getFilesDir() + "/scanner.mp3'></speak>"
```

I have also tried it with:

```
"<speak>What you hear is: <audio src='"+ R.raw.scanner +"'></speak>"
```

And also tried it with:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/scanner.mp3");
String myString = "<speak>What you hear is: <audio src='"+ uri +"'></speak>";
```

If I run my application, I can hear "What you hear is" but not the audio.

The audio file (scanner.mp3) is in: src\main\res\raw

If I use a URL instead, it works fine. E.g.:

```
<speak>What you hear is: <audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-website-resources-1183x/dice-die-roll.mp3' /></speak>
```

What's wrong with my code?